# Список глобальных переменных

Tags: c++

Имеется больше тысячи cpp файлов, необходимо в текстовом файле вывести список всех глобальных переменных.

Есть ли специальный софт для решения подобной задачи? Или необходимо писать свой скрипт?

Comment: может [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/)?

Comment: IMHO свой скрипт, анализирующий вывод nm для .o соответствующих Вашим .cpp. 

Если речь о C++ и функции Вас не интересуют, то нужно выбирать переменные с типами символов `B,D,R` в выводе nm.

В винде g++ добавляет знак `_` перед именем переменной, а в линуксе - нет.


Только учтите, если переменная была объявлена в .cpp как extern, но не используется, то в .o она (даже среди `U`) не упоминается.

Comment: @avp, дели такое задание при приеме на стажировку, из чего следует что я совсем неопытен. Ваш ответ выглядит очень правдоподобным, поэтому хотелось бы в нём разобраться, но я ничего не понимаю. Не знаю, что такое nm, .o

Comment: @Артём Девятов
Детектор показывает задачу на стажировку в Яндекс. Попробуйте эту штуковину. http://opencxx.sourceforge.net/ или llvm фронтенд там тоже вроде есть доступ к синтаксическому анализатору для грамматики C++ напрямую из кода.

Comment: @Артём Девятов, .o это *объектные* модули, результат трансляции .cpp компилятором. 

nm - утилита (в винде у меня она в составе mingw (компиляторы gcc и утилиты gnu для винды)), которая печатает таблицу символов объектного/исполняемого модуля.

Вообще, почитайте о процессе (стадиях) компиляции. 

Если у Вас есть выбор между \*nix и виндой, то советую делать в \*nix.

Comment: @avp: может, опубликуете ответ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот, поподробнее об использовании nm (см. `man nm`) для получения списка глобальных переменных, определенных в заданных .cpp файлах. Я подразумеваю, что интересны только переменные (и константы), но не функции.

Для примера сделаем пару С++ файлов.

```
// ext1.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int esum,
  e1 = 1;
extern int e2;

int const  econ1 = 2;   // в c++ это НЕ ГЛОБАЛЬНАЯ КОНСТАНТА !!!
extern int const econ;  // а это ГЛОБАЛЬНАЯ(!!!), но не определенная здесь

void sumext();

int 
main ()
{
  sumext(); // помещает сумму всех глобальных (кроме esum) в esum
  cout << "DoubleSum: " << esum + econ + e1 + e2 << '\n';
}

// ext2.cpp
extern int esum, e1;
int e2 = 2;

extern int const econ = 3;  // ГЛОБАЛЬНАЯ КОНСТАНТА, определена здесь

void sumext()
{
  esum = e1 + e2 + econ;
}
```

Оттранслируем их, получив объектные файлы ext1.o и ext2.o

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ -c  ext1.cpp ext2.cpp
```

и посмотрим на вывод утилиты nm

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ nm ext[12].o

ext1.o:
000000000000009f t _GLOBAL__sub_I_esum
000000000000005f t _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
                 U _Z6sumextv
000000000000000c r _ZL5econ1
                 U _ZNSolsEi
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
                 U _ZSt4cout
0000000000000004 b _ZStL8__ioinit
                 U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
                 U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_c
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 U __dso_handle
0000000000000000 D e1
                 U e2
                 U econ
0000000000000000 B esum
0000000000000000 T main

ext2.o:
0000000000000000 T _Z6sumextv
                 U e1
0000000000000000 D e2
0000000000000000 R econ
                 U esum
```

Легко заметить, что инициализированные переменные e1 и e2 отмечены флагом D, неинециализированная переменная esum отмечена флагом B, а глобальная константа флагом R.

В файлах, где эти переменные и константа являются внешними, они отмечены флагом U.

Для первого приближения к решению можно написать скрипт на awk

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ for i in ext[12].o; do echo Global variables defined in $i; nm $i | awk 'NF == 3 && ($2 == "D" || $2 == "B" || $2 == "R") { print $2 "  " $3 }'; done
Global variables defined in ext1.o
D  e1
B  esum
Global variables defined in ext2.o
D  e2
R  econ
```

Ну и наконец, сделать исполнимый модуль и посмотреть, работает ли программа

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ -o ext12 ext1.o ext2.o
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./ext12 
DoubleSum: 12
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Comment: Прекрасно, жаль, что я не рекрутёр Яндекса.

Comment: Я просто обязан разобраться в столь подробном ответе! Но перед этим хотелось бы уточнить вот что:
Правильно ли я понял, что это можно сделать на винде?
Получится ли данным методом получить результат в данном формате?
1.cpp var1 var2
2.cpp anothervar
3.cpp
4.cpp onemorevar

Comment: В винде надо скачать MinGW (для nm) и Unixutils (для awk). И учесть, что g++ добавляет знак подчеркивания перед именем глобальной переменной.

Наверняка у M$ есть аналоги, только мне они неизвестны. Погуглите или спросите у кого-нибудь.

Comment: Аналог nm для Visual Studio -- dumpbin. (Его, правда, надо запускать из под Visual Studio Command Prompt или в .bat-файле после `call vsvars32.bat`, т.к. он требует настроенных переменных окружения.)

Comment: @avp, а можно поподробнее, что считается глобальной переменной, а что нет? Считать ли константы переменными? И почему определённая константа считается глобальной, а неопределённая - нет?

Comment: @Артём Девятов, считать ли константы переменными?

Строго говоря, конечно, не стоит. Также как имена функций. Просто так получилось, что вместо термина *глобальный символ* мы тут говорили "глобальная переменная" (правда функции сюда не включили). 

Вы бы уточнили, какие именно глобальные объекты Вас интересуют. Вообще список их типов можно найти в `man nm`.

--

Что такое глобальная переменная? По простому, если в разных единицах компиляции мы используем одно и тоже имя для переменной, а после линковки все эти имена ссылаются на один и тот же адрес, то это глобальная переменная. (места мало).

Comment: (продолжение)

Конечно, такие имена надо как-то (средствами языка) выделить среди других. Вот тут-то мы и подошли к Вашему вопросу

    И почему определённая константа считается глобальной, а неопределённая - нет?

Наверное я непонятно написал в комментариях в программе. По правилам С++ (на мой вкус дурацким) описания в файле вне функции

    int a; // глобальная (память здесь)
    extern int b; // глобальная (память не здесь)
    int const c = 0; // не глобальная !!!
    extern int const c1; // глобальная (память не здесь)
    extern int const c2 = 0; // глобальная (память здесь) !!!

(опять

Comment: @avp, спасибо большое :)
Раз уж вы упомянули про правила C++, подскажите, где их можно посмотреть?

Comment: (опять продолжение)

@Артём Девятов, мне кажется смысл ясен.

Думаю у меня тут комментарии уже закончились. Если вопросы остались, то лучше откройте новую тему.

--

Пришлось удалить и опять вставить комментарий (лимит).

>>> Где посмотреть правила С++?

В любом учебнике.

@Артём Девятов, здесь я уже откликаться не смогу!!!

Answer (score 2):

Вначале берем [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) либо [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) (в линукс дистрибутивах есть в репозитариях) и натравливаем на исходники. На выходе получаем специальный tag файл, в котором собрана информация о всех переменных, функциях и тому подобное. А дальше либо учиться разбирать формат tag файла, либо воспользоваться встроенными средствами.

Comment: Ну если эти глобальные переменные используются в других модулях, то extern вылавливается grep'ом. Правда остаются за кулисами те, которые вне модуля не используются, но могут. Так же можно проанализировать список символов после линковщика, но это уже не исходные файлы.

Comment: мне встречались народные умельцы, которые делали `#define global extern`, а потом писали `global int a;`. повысекай их таких:)

Но нужно подумать, что хочется - один раз решить задачу, решать эту задачу регулярно, но для какого то определенного проекта или делать универсальный инструмент.

Comment: Там grep не поможет. Только розги.

Comment: @KoVadim: чтобы решить задачу регулярно, нужен полный настоящий парсер C++. Без него вы не сможете понять, является ли конструкция

    A B(C);

объявлением глобальной переменной `B` типа `A`, и вызова конструктора с аргументом `C`, или forward-декларацией функции `B` с типом аргумента `C` и типом возвращаемого значения `A`.

Comment: @VladD, а cpp не?

Comment: @klopp: вы имеете в виду препроцесор? Он ничего умного не делает, просто подставляет #define'ы и копипастит текст #include'ов.

Comment: @VladD, да, ну хотя бы от примитивной дури избавиться. А после этого уже разбираться с парсерами. Хотя задача вообще дурацкая изначально. Цель-то в чём? Ну, допустим, выявим мы эти "глобальные переменные", дальше что? 

Comment: может быть в компании, где работает ТС, такая мания - избегать глобальных переменных. И ТС задали такую задачу - разработать программы, которые бы измеряли их кол-во (например при каждом коммите).

Comment: И что нужно делать по факту обнаружения? (да я прикалываюсь больше, на самом деле не смешно)

Comment: @KoVadim, дали такую задачу при приёме на стажировку, задание на умение находить и разбираться в разных инструментах. Само по себе её выполнение никакого смысла не несет.
К сожалению, я ничего не смог понять в ctags...
У вас нет хотя бы одного несложного рабочего примера использования ctags? В мануале одни только параметры и их описания.

Comment: Немножко погуглить и все находится. Вот [раз](http://citforum.ru/operating_systems/unixprofi/glava4_1.shtml) - там внутри статьи есть.

Но я бы поступил бы так. Сделал маленький проектик (уровня хелло-ворлд) и  распарсил ctags. Поизучать. Очень полезно.

Но если лень, то во краткая подсказка. Все, что начинается на знак восклицания - комментарий. Другие строки имеют вид "идентификатор имя_файла /строка из файла/ КОД  детали", где КОД - это буква `s` в случае структуры, `m` - если это поле структуры, `v` - переменные (это похоже то, что нужно). Немножко кода и у Вас есть список всех переменных

Answer (score 2):

Не надейтесь вручную найти все глобальные переменные, анализируя исходный код: синтаксис C++ безнадёжно сложен для того, чтобы написать сколько-нибудь подходящий парсер за короткое время. Вам нужно воспользоваться существующим парсером.

На [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1904363/276994) рекомендуют попросить компилятор (который уж точно знает, как распарсить ваш проект) создать map-файл.

Вот как его включить в gcc: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html.
У меня map-файл сгенерировался следующим вызовом:

```
g++ -Wl,-Map,maptest.map maptest.cpp
```

В нём довольно много лишнего, так что вам, если вы пойдёте этим путём, придётся разобраться, как этот самый map-файл читать. Насколько я понимаю, вам нужна секция `.bss`, исключая переменные из модулей, лежащих в `/usr/lib`.

В MSVC можно тоже включить map-файл через опции компоновщика (`/MAP` или Project properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate map file), тут тоже придётся научиться разбирать файл (хотя субъективно выглядит проще), ищите данные из своих объектных модулей, не отмеченных как функция (буква f в одной из колонок).

---

Попробовал идею @avp с `nm`, она гораздо лучше. Разберитесь в том, что такое объектный файл, и используйте её.

Для MSVC есть аналогичная утилита dumpbin.